# Expose a film to a screen

Tags: polaroid

Long story short, I would like to "map" a 5.5" lcd screen to check the light distribution of it, to see where the light is more intense and where it is weaker.

This is for an LCD 3d printer which has a UV LED light source at the bottom that is projected on to an LCD screen of which pixels turn on to let the light through to generate images for each layer of the model that is printing.

So because the projected light comes from a single point it will travel more to reach the sides of the screen which is theorized to be about 30% weaker on the sides.

I would like to use somehow a photographic film set on the 5.5" screen, expose a full screen image for like 0.1 seconds and be able to see on the film the transitions from stronger to weaker spots.

Would this be possible? Could I somehow use a polaroid film? Which would be the most simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use a device made to measure light output instead of trying to hack this with film?

Comment: A device would give steps, would not be smooth and precise enough and would be more difficult to be converted to a mask, a picture would be easier to convert to have it displayed on the lcd .

Comment: vtc b/c This Q is about using photographic equipment and materials for non-photographic purpose, namely 3D printer diagnostics.

Comment: Are you sure the inside of the device is dark enough for photographic film or paper to work?  Since it operates using UV, it may leak or produce visible or IR light.  You'd also need materials sensitive to UV.

Answer (score 2):

You could use film but I think you will have better luck with photographic paper. Procure some at a local camera shop or on line. You will need a red safe light bulb and two plastic trays. Procure some paper developer and fixer. You can experiment, under red safe light conditions, taping the photo paper to the screen and then exposing same. Then develop and fix the paper. Perhaps this will work however a light meter reading might be best. You can take various readings at multiple locations. You are looking at the uniformity of the screen brightness.

Comment: Which of them would be simpler to use?

Comment: Beyond any doubt, paper will be simpler. 1. It has low ISO 2. can be handled under safelight conditions. 3. Is developed in a tray under safelight, you can pull it out of the developer or leave it in, all the time watching the image as it materializes.

Comment: Is photo paper sensitive to UV light?

Comment: Without much exceptions, all silver based photo materials are sensitive to UV light. The shorter the frequency the more energetic. Thus these materials naturally respond to blue, violet and UV and X-ray etc.